# binding custom control to an external button

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer, design-time

I have a custom control that i'm using in an external application. I want to bind a click event of a random button in the **application** to add data to my **control**.

Is something like that even possible?? Basically what i was thinking was creating a property in my control that allows a developer to add a button control to it at design time. And then when the application is run, any clicks registered on the button will be forwarded to a method in the custom control to add data.

Is this doable? if so, can someone explain what needs to be done exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property of type `Button` in your custom control. Then when you put an instance of custom control on the designer, for that property, you will see a dropdown that shows all `Button` instances on the form which you can select one of them. It's enough to add a method to click event of the button in setter of the property:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private Button addButton;
    public Button AddButton
    {
        get { return addButton; }
        set
        {
            if (addButton != null)
                addButton.Click -= new EventHandler(addButton_Click);

            addButton = value;

            if (addButton != null)
                addButton.Click += new EventHandler(addButton_Click);
        }
    }

    void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Add Button Clicked!");
    }
}
```

When you put it on designer, for `AddButton` property, a list o available buttons on the form will be shown. it's enough to choose one of them, then the behavior which you want (here in the example, showing the message box) will attach to click event of that button.

[image]

Comment: To test it, it's enough to copy ans paste the codes in a file in your project and then build the solution and put an instance of `MyControl` on a form and see its `AddButton` proprty in designer. Then select one of buttons and run the program and click on that button.

Comment: perfect.
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, the permission is not limited to the answers to your question. In all questions you can vote for good answers. Also in your questions, while you can accept only one answer, but you can vote for all good answers including the accepted one. - I'll remove the comment after you see, to keep the comments clean :)

Comment: I read the whole page in the link you posted. I think i got a good idea of how things work now :)
I'll be sure to always vote on accepted answers and such. Thanks again